# Automation testing for video chat web application upto 20 users?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a video conference web app for multiple users to login and chat . I want to automate below scenario by using selenium and Jmeter 
Scenario -
test this application for max of 20 users login into the app and do interaction with others

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

If the maximum load you're going to create is only 20 concurrent virtual users and you're going to use real browsers driven by [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) for this - you can go for [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/) and use the programming language of your choice.

If you intend to use JMeter - out of the box JMeter doesn't provide any browser automation functionality however you can utilize [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) plugin for this, the plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) and once you code your test logic using WebDriver Samplers you can [add more virtual users](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and each virtual user will kick off its own browser instance

Comment: Will we validate the video in these cases or only the latency and other performance metrics